# Trying to convert a string into Long and then breaking up each digit

Tags: java

I have an assignment which asks me to ask for a 12 digit number from the input(must be taken as String) and calculate the last digit out of it. However, it returns an error at `digits[i] = temp%10;` saying I can't do this. Does anyone else have any experience turning this?

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Exercise05_47{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] digits;
    int d13 = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the first 12 digits of an ISBN-13 as a string: ");
    String ISBN = sc.nextLine();
    Long realISBN = Long.parseLong(ISBN);
    Long temp = realISBN;
    Long ten = 10L;
    if(ISBN.length() != 12)
    {
        System.out.println(ISBN+" is an invalid input");
        return;

    }
    else 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
        {
            digits[i] = temp%10 ;
            temp /=10;
        }
        d13 = 10-(digits[0]+3*digits[1]+digits[2]+3*digits[3]+digits[4]+3*digits[5]+digits[6]+3*digits[7]+digits[8]+3*digits[9]+digits[10]+3*digits[11])%10;
        if(d13 ==10)
        {
            d13=0;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The ISBN-13 number is "+ISBN+d13);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think you'll need to do replace this --> `int[] digits;
        int d13 = 0;` with this --> `long[] digits =  new long[length];
        long d13 = 0;`

Comment: replace `Long temp = realISBN;` with `long temp = realISBN;` and `temp%10` with `(int)(temp%10)`

Comment: @IlyaBursov downcasting a long to an int is unsafe and as such, is a bad idea

Comment: @Dici we're downcasting result of modulo operation, in this case it is 100% safe

Comment: @IlyaBursov yep. The check digit (the last one) can be "X". But then I spotted OP is asking the user to chop the last digit off.

Comment: @IlyaBursov mm yeah makes sense

Comment: also, you need to replace `int[] digits;` with `int[] digits = new int[13];` to make it work

Comment: Apart from good comments on your code, why dont you just get last character in the string and convert it to int?

Comment: @Ilya Bursov As mentioned in the comment - `replace Long temp = realISBN;` with `long temp = realISBN;` Is this really required as Java will usually translate a Long into a long automatically(and vice versa).

Comment: @YuganderKrishanSingh not really, but boxing/unboxing in loop is quite inefficient

Answer (score 4):

You can't store a `Long` (or `long`) into a `int[]` since a long integer uses more bytes than a regular integer. This means, in particular, that not all `long` values can be represented as an `int`. One way of fixing your issue would be to use `long[]` instead.

Technically you could also parse the ISBNs as `int` but usually ids are always longs to support a very large number of values, some ISBNs wouldn't actually fit in an `int`, hence my answer (see this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number), it tells you ISBNs can have up to 13 numbers, which exceeds `int` maximum capacity of roughly 2 billion).

You can find some information about the size and range of values of the different primitive types on [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types) or [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details.

However, as *Ilya Bursov* pointed out, your array only ever contains digits, hence less than 10. You can fit any digit in a `short` or an `int`, so it is safe to cast the `long` value down to a smaller primitive type in this case, i.e. `(int) (temp % 10)`.

Comment: so should i also convert d13, which is what I am looking for, also from int into Long?

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, it is pretty easy to prove d13 will never exceed 2^31 - 1, which is the maximum integer value. Therefore, it doesn't need to be a `long`.

Comment: Thanks a million! Youve been great helpXD

Comment: Hope you read the last update, Ilya actually had the best answer. I didn't really read the logic at first, I only suggested a way to make the code compile but his proposition makes more sense for what you're doing